# Time complexity of finding common elements between two sorted sequences

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

Given 2 sorted sequences of A and B and A being of size n and B being of size n^2 keys, I want to find their common elements and will print the output. What would be the most time-efficient way to solve this problem? I think it would be either O(n^2) or Theta(n^2) or O(nlgn) or Theta(nlgn).

I know, for example, if I had two sequences of size m and size n, the most efficient way to solve that would take O(m+n), but not sure how that would translate for this problem.

Comment: @atanay - No, since the sequences are sorted, you can perform binary search on the bigger list!

Comment: Oh right! so sorry. but my point still remains, there is no difference between this case and the general problem, I just forgot that the general problem can be solved in either O(n+m) or O(min(n,m)log(max(n,m)))

Answer (score 1):

Since it is given that the sequences are sorted, one of the optimal ways over the brute force method would be to iterate through the elements of the smaller sequence, and perform a binary search over the elements in the larger sequence (within the iteration). Whenever you get a binary search result as successful, then that element being searched is common in both the sequences!

In this way, the time complexity (worst-case) would be equal to iteration count of smaller sequence * binary search on large sequence = n * log (n<sup>2</sup>) = n * 2 log n = O(n log n).

Kindly do note that you're reducing the cycles by selecting the smaller sequence for iteration, and doing binary search over bigger sorted sequence.